# Dynamic Route Resolution with Rust's Axum Framework

Tags: rust, webserver, endpoint, rust-axum

I'm currently implementing a web service from scratch using the Axum framework. The goal of this service is to access and read/write files or directories on a target directory.

Want I want to achieve are the following routes:

```
PUT https://<domain>/<directory>/?some_query=value
PUT https://<domain>/<directory>/<file>?some_other_query=value
```

Basically if the route ends with a '/' it is a directory, otherwise a file.

What I understood from reading their docs is, that their route wildcards do not support something like this, e.g. i have the following Router defined:

```
Router::new()
  .route("/*path", get(my_get_handler))
  .route("/*path", put(my_put_handler)));
```

For example:

```
/dir/sub/sub2/file.txt -> Should be a file
/dir/sub/sub2/sub3/ -> Should be a dir
/dir/sub/sub2/something -> Should be a file
```

What i thought would be possible is something like this:

```
Router::new().route("/*path/*file", put(handler));
```

How could this be achieved using the axum framework?

Comment: You can use [http::Request::uri](https://docs.rs/http/0.2.9/http/request/struct.Request.html#method.uri) to get URI of the request inside the handler.

Comment: Since they have different query parameters but route to the same handler, would that still be possible when looking at the uri and writing the logic myself? @AleksanderKrauze

Comment: You can have one handler match multiple HTTP methods, and get used method from [Request](https://docs.rs/http/latest/http/request/struct.Request.html#method.method) as well.

Answer (score 0):

What you have will work just fine, the full path is preserved when using a [wildcard](https://docs.rs/axum/latest/axum/struct.Router.html#wildcards) pattern:

```
.route("/*path", get(file_handler))
```

```
use axum::extract::Path;
use axum::response::IntoResponse;

async fn file_handler(Path(path): Path<String>) -> impl IntoResponse {
    println!("{path}");
}
```

- `GET /dir/sub/sub2/file.txt` will print `dir/sub/sub2/file.txt`
- `GET /dir/sub/sub2/sub3/` will print `dir/sub/sub2/sub3/`
- `GET /dir/sub/sub2/something` will print `dir/sub/sub2/something`

So it is simply up to you how to interpret that path. What you want is different from how the standard `Path` and `PathBuf` interpret things, since a trailing `/` is pretty much ignored. But I don't see anything wrong with a simple `path.ends_with('/')` to check if a file or directory is desired.

If you were wanting to route to different handlers based on the existence of a trailing slash then you're right this is not supported directly from a `.route()` pattern. Handle the distinction manually.